# Argument 1 passed to Illuminate\Database\Grammar::parameterize() must be of the type array - Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I am save data into my database but i get this error

> Type error: Argument 1 passed to >Illuminate\Database\Grammar::parameterize() must be of the type array, string given

Researching other related questions, i have tried to solve this issue but none of them has helped me yet.  Below is my code

```
  $student = Student::findOrFail($id)
  if($request->file('imported-file'))
     {
         $path = $request->file('imported-file')->getRealPath();
         $data = Excel::load($path, function($reader)
     {
         })->get();

        if(!empty($data) && $data->count())
       {
         foreach ($data->toArray() as $row)
         {
           if(!empty($row))
           {
             $dataArray[] =
             [
               'name' => $row['name'],
               'grade' => $row['grade'],
               'age' => $row['age'],
               'parent' => $row['parent'],



             ];
           }
       }

       if(!empty($dataArray))
       {
        $student->teachers()->attach(\App\Teacher::create($dataArray)->id);                   
        }
```

}

Comment: You're missing some relevant parts of the code. You're checking if $data is empty but the code doesn't show where $data comes from. Which line of the code gives you the error?

Comment: BTW, you're fetching student object incorrectly. Student::all() fetches all students from the database and later filters the collection. You could just do $student = Student::findOrFail($id);

Comment: @jedrzej.kurylo, please look at my update. and it looks as if the error is with this line `$student->teachers()->attach(\App\Teacher::create($dataArray)->id);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try replacing

```
$student->teachers()->attach(\App\Teacher::create($dataArray)->id);
```

with

```
$student->teachers()->createMany($dataArray);
```

Answer (score 0):

The create method is for creating a single model. It takes an associative array of 'field' => 'value'. You are passing some nested arrays to it.

```
Model::create(['field' => 'value', 'anotherfield' => 'anothervalue']);
```

You will have to create each `Teacher` model individually.

Comment: I guess then the error would be opposite: expected string, array given.

Comment: considering there is nothing else to go on, that is something that is a problem with the only code available  ... more code would be good to find where this is coming from

Comment: I have updated my code. The data is actually coming from a file